# Localizing XML file parsed

Tags: xml-parsing, localization, xcode6, ios8.1

I made an ios / cocoa app a few months ago and now I'm trying to localize it. I have already localized XIBs, Strings, etc. successfully.

The problem that I am facing now is that I am parsing an XML (XML-SAX) file to build a list and retrieve more information over the itens, like a tree of information.

The parser simply extract data from the lines.xml file. I tried to localize the file and change every string inside the the just created versions of lines.xml, but I can only see the original strings being displayed.

Please, let me know if you need any other information.

A little help here would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found some not so clever way to do so..... it works but I think it is ugly:

```
if([language  isEqual: @"en"]){
    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"lines-en"];

}else{
    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"lines"];

}

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:s ofType:@"xml"];
```